# Sprite animation Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, animation, sprite

I created a game in AndroidStudio, where you can move right and left through the buttons. Now I would like to add an animation. I have this image:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTeWI.png) 

How do I change the animation when I click the left button and then stop it when no touch the button? 
Is there a guide? Thanks for all.

Answer (score 4):

First of all you have to create a xml and place the images. You have 6 frames in the sprite, you have to cut it making 6 images. Create a xml (e.g. run_animation.xml) and reference the images in there. For example like this:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/run_0001" android:duration="50"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/run_0002" android:duration="50"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/run_0003" android:duration="50"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/run_0004" android:duration="50"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/run_0005" android:duration="50"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/run_0006" android:duration="50"/>
</animation-list>
```

If you don't want to loop the animation, you can use this in the xml: `android:oneshot="true"`

For example:

`<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="true">`

Java:

```
runAnimation.setImageResource(R.drawable.run_animation);
AnimationDrawable idleAnimation = (AnimationDrawable)runAnimation.getDrawable();
idleAnimation.start();
```

In order to run the animation using a button, place the Java code above in the button click listener. For example:

```
btnRight.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // run animation
        runAnimation.setImageResource(R.drawable.run_animation);
        AnimationDrawable idleAnimation = (AnimationDrawable)runAnimation.getDrawable();
        idleAnimation.start();
    }
});
```